# WP7 Binding on collapsed/non visible controls

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have a Listbox in a PivotItem, as well as a ListBox in a Grid which is normally collapsed.  Both ListBoxes have their ItemSource and SelectedItem properties bound to a view model.  I put a breakpoint on the getters and setters of the ViewModel properties and noticed that they get called even if the bound controls are not visible or collapsed.  Is it possible to have the binding only active when the bound control can be interacted with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you want to write code to unbind and rebind it. Not possible with pure markup.

Comment: Is there a best practice around this, or do you typically just let the framework do the binding even if the binding will possibly never be used?

Comment: WP7 hasn't been around long enough to accumulate best practices. As a rule, once widespread patterns emerge in the use of code behind to compensate the shortcomings of markup, Microsoft tends to extend or revise the markup to support whatever the unsupported common use cases might be. The case you are considering is essentially a cost/benefit question: is the inefficiency causing UX performance problems, and if so is the expected improvement worth the code mess?